# How to make the data to only row instead of multiple rows for account-number

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the result what i'm getting and what i'm supposed to get is to be in one row

```
  AccountNumber  Name   UnitNumber    AdmStatus    AdmitDate    Insurance1  Insurance2  Insurance3  Insurance4  Insurance5 
  V000123456       FERG     M000123456  DIS IN      11/11/2019      ins1                
  V000123456       FERG     M000123456  DIS IN      11/11/2019                ins2
```

but i need the result to be in row with insurance 2

```
       AccountNumber     Name   UnitNumber    AdmStatus    AdmitDate    Insurance1  Insurance2   Insurance3 Insurance4  Insurance5 
       V000123456      FERG     M000123456  DIS IN      11/11/2019      ins1         ins2
```

here is the query i have attached

```
     SELECT
          AccountNumber

          ,case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='1' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END AS 'Insurance1'
          ,case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='2' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END AS 'Insurance2'
          ,case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='3' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END AS 'Insurance3'
          ,case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='4' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END AS 'Insurance4'
          ,case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='5' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END AS 'Insurance5'

     FROM BarVisits bv
left outer join BarInsuranceOrder bio on bio.SourceID = bv.SourceID and bv.VisitID = bio.VisitID

    WHERE AccountNumber ='1213456'

     group by AccountNumber
         ,bio.InsuranceOrderID
          ,bio.InsuranceID
```

Comment: Rather than completely changing your question (which you've attempted to do several times now), please try asking a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation functions for the columns and fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
 SELECT AccountNumber,
        MAX(case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='1' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END) AS Insurance1,
        MAX(case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='2' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END AS Insurance2,
        MAX(case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='3' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END AS Insurance3,
        MAX(case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='4' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END) AS Insurance4
        MAX(case when bio.InsuranceOrderID ='5' then bio.InsuranceID ELSE '' END) AS Insurance5
 FROM BarVisits bv LEFT JOIN
      BarInsuranceOrder bio
      ON bio.SourceID = bv.SourceID AND bv.VisitID = bio.VisitID
WHERE AccountNumber = 'V000123456'
GROUP BY AccountNumber
```